# Firebase reCaptcha keeps stalling and freezing website - Vuejs, Firebase V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I've got the following code that should enable recaptcha and allow users to log in using their phone number. However, whenever I add a phone number and click sign in, the site just freezes, the recpatcha box appears but then nothing happens. I can't see any errors from my console.

Vue3 on Vite using Firebase V9

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth"

const auth = getAuth()
const userPhone = ref(null)
const phoneCode = ref('+44')
const conCode = ref('');
const smsSent = ref(false)
const confirmationResult = ref(null)

const initRecaptcha = () => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
    size: 'invisible',
    'callback': (response) => {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      console.log(response)
    }}, auth)
  },1000)
}

initRecaptcha()

const SignIn = async() => {
  const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier
  const phonenumber = `${phoneCode.value}${userPhone.value}`
  console.log(`${phoneCode.value}${userPhone.value}`)
  signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phonenumber, appVerifier)
    .then((confirmationresult) => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      // ...
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationresult;
      smsSent.value = true
      alert('SMS sent')
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
      window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
        grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
      })
      console.log('Theres been an error',  error)
  });
}

const confirmCode = async() => {
  const code = conCode.value
  try {
    const result = await confirmationResult.value.confirm(code)
    // User signed in successfully.
    const user = result.user;
    console.log('User details are ', user)
    // ...
} catch (error) {
    // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
    // ...
    console.log('BIG ERROR', error)
};
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="px-14 mt-12">
  <div id="re-element"></div>
  <form v-if="smsSent == false" id="sign-in-form">
    <!-- Input to enter the phone number -->
    <div class="flex relative shadow-md">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 my-auto align-middle flex text-gray-300 text-center pointer-events-none"><p class="flex items-middle">(+44)0</p></div>
      <input
        v-model="userPhone" type="tel" id="phone-number"
        class="px-3 py-4 flex-1
        pl-16 font-extralight text-gray-600 relative bg-opacity-0 bg-transparent border-2 border-gray-900 bg-gray-800outline-none focus:z-10 focus:outline-none w-full"
      />
      <label class="absolute top-2.5 ml-4 px-8 pt-1 -z-1 text-normal font-light duration-300 origin-0 text-gray-500" for="phone-number">Enter your phone number...</label>
      <!-- Sign-in button -->
      <button @click.prevent="SignIn" class="flex-0 px-4 border-2 border-gray-900" id="sign-in-button">Sign-in</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form v-else id="verification-code-form">
    <!-- Input to enter the verification code -->
    <div class="flex">
      <input v-model="conCode" class="" type="text" id="verification-code">
      <label class="" for="verification-code">Enter the verification code...</label>
    </div>
    <!-- Button that triggers code verification -->
    <button @click.prevent="confirmCode" class="text-grey-800" id="verify-code-button" value="Verify Code">Verify code</button>
    <!-- Button to cancel code verification -->
    <button class="" id="cancel-verify-code-button">Cancel</button>
  </form>
  <div id="phone-sign-in-recaptcha"></div>
  </div> 
</template>

<style scoped>
input:focus-within ~ label,
input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  @apply transform scale-75 -translate-y-3.5 px-6;
}
input:focus-within ~ label {
  @apply text-blue-500;
}
</style>
```

Am I missing something wildly obvious? I've been stuck of this for some time haha. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note, there is no need to mark a function as `async` if you're not using `await` in it.